# Maxwell equations for $F^{\mu \nu \rho}F_{\mu \nu \rho}$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, field-theory

I am trying to find equivalent of Maxwell equations for 2 form gauge theory. My question is

1. Do we get $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu \nu\ \rho}$ using Euler-Lagrange equation of motions?
2. How do we get the remaining two equations? Does it have equivalent of Jacobi identity?

How does it generalize to higher forms?

Answer (score 2):

For a $p$-form gauge field, $C_{(p)}$ the field strength is a $p+1$ form,
$$
F_{(p+1)} = d C_{(p)} \quad \implies \quad d F_{(p+1)} = 0 .
$$
The field strength is invariant under gauge transformations
$$
C_{(p)} \to C_{(p)} + d \Lambda_{(p-1)}.
$$
The basic Lagrangian for this field is
$$
L = F_{(p+1)}  \wedge \star F_{(p+1)} 
$$
The corresponding equations of motion are
$$
d \star F_{(p+1)} = 0 
$$